# Android - how do I place an image on top of my existing layout through code?

Tags: android, android-webview, android-imageview

I have a `layout` in which I am displaying a `webview`. I want to add images on top of the `webview` at specific places through code.

Can some one please tell me how to do that?

The translucent background example in API Demos makes the view cover the whole screen. I want to place only a small image and at a specific location (origin not 0,0)

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried putting both the WebView and the ImageView inside an Absolute Layout?  This should let you specify the X/Y location of your image and by ordering make it constantly drawn over the webview.

EDIT: check out the Absolute layout:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout-objects.html#absolutelayout

Comment: Never heard of an X-Y layout. Are there any examples around for this layout? Thanks

Comment: Sorry, XY layout is from another framework.  Check out the absolute layout.

Comment: AbsoluteLayout is genereally not a good idea, as it ties you to fixed X/Y Coordinates - once those change (i.e. different screen sizes etc..), your view should look all messed up. I followed the given link, however there is no section on Absolute Layout? EDIT: Just saw that AbsoluteLayout is deprecated - probably a good choice.

Answer (score 2):

AbsoluteLayout is deprecated and if that bothers you, you may want to look for alternative.
I have put an example in my blog post here. It might not be exactly what you are after, but should give you an idea:

http://anothermobiledeveloper.blogspot.com/2011/10/using-relativelayout-instead-of.html